# Limit image size to div

Tags: html, css

I've tried several methods but can't seem to get my LinkedIn logo to fit. I've tried to inherit as well as setting max height and width to 100% to limit. But it just keeps going full size.

Do I need to use some other form of container?

```css
body {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 234);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: FoundrySterlingOT3W03-Bold, FoundrySterlingOT3W10- Bold, Arial, Helvetica, sans- serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  right: 0px;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.nav-custom {
  padding-top: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-custom>a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="linkedin" src="linkedin logo.png">
  <nav position: fixed; class="nav-custom" ;>
    <a href=#home>Home</a>
    <a href=#skills>Skills</a>
    <a href=#about>About</a>
    <a href=#contact>Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Portfolio.css">>
```

Comment: try, setting width: 100% and height: auto in .linkedin class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this fit your demand

I put the logo in the nav section and make it a fit height width in px

```css
.linkedin {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px; 
}
```

also using flex to align to it's other element in nav

```css
.nav-custom {
  padding-top: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
  body {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    color:rgb(0, 255, 234);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: FoundrySterlingOT3W03-Bold,FoundrySterlingOT3W10- 
Bold,Arial,Helvetica,sans- 
serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    right: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.linkedin {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px; 
}
.nav-custom {
    padding-top: 1px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-custom > a{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;

}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <nav style="position: fixed;" class="nav-custom";>
      <a><img class="linkedin" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png"></a>
      <a href=#home>Home</a>
      <a href=#skills>Skills</a>
      <a href=#about>About</a>
      <a href=#contact>Contact</a>
    </nav></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Portfolio.css">
```

Comment: changed the answer including explanation. you can find it in details now i think.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

`width="value" height="value"` needs to be added
so `<img class="linkedin" src="linkedin logo.png">` needs to be `<img class="linkedin" src="linkedin logo.png" width="value" height="value">`
so all together it would be

```html
 <img class="linkedin" src="linkedin logo.png" width="value" height="value">
    <nav position: fixed; class="nav-custom";>
      <a href=#home>Home</a>
      <a href=#skills>Skills</a>
      <a href=#about>About</a>
      <a href=#contact>Contact</a>
    </nav></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Portfolio.css">>  

   body {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    color:rgb(0, 255, 234);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: FoundrySterlingOT3W03-Bold,FoundrySterlingOT3W10- 
Bold,Arial,Helvetica,sans- 
serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    right: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.linkedin {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit; 
}
.nav-custom {
    padding-top: 1px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-custom > a{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    max-height: 100px;

}
```

Comment: I follow the details of your solution, and it is fine, but try to clean up the format of the answer a bit. No point in a snippet if It doesn't accurately reflect the code.